Strapi Relational tables data not showing
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/vvvxUYo7.png)
i added two photos that i have given public full access to modules and courses and linked courses to module but my response in postman doesnt show the linked course with module i have implemented many to many relationship and my database also show modules_courses_lnk has that data but why not showing in response.Hope to get help from you
I tried with postman and the response doesnt contain courses data enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode
